# How to change the way Talend formulates SQL queries in a JDBC connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, talend, data-quality

In Talend Data Quality, I have configured a JDBC connection to an OpenEdge database and it's working fine.

I can pull the list of tables and select columns to analyse, but when executing analysis, I get this :

**Table "DBGSS.SGSSGSS" cannot be found.**

This is because it does not specify a schema, only the database name - **DBGSS**.

How can I make it specify database, **schema** and then the table name ? Or just the table name, its would work too.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tDBConnection`  component that give you the right to specify a schéma

Then , use it with the option of `Use Existing connection`

See below documentation , https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/db-generic/tdbconnection

Comment: This is for TOS Data Integration, and my question is about TOS Data Quality. 

Essentially, the problem is that TOS does not recognize schemas in my OpenEdge JDBC connection. 

Normally, the connection in the metadata unfolds like this :
- Connection
---- Database
-------- Schema
------------ Table

Whereas for my OpenEdge connection it is :
- Connection
---- Database
--------Table

So, the query formulator just thinks that <database name>.<table name> is the complete table name, but it is not. 

So, I want to make it query just <table name> or <database name>.<schema>.<table>